# Magento 2: How to add prodcut into cart and then get them?

Tags: magento2

Magento version: 2.0.0

How to add the product into shopping cart? How about this work-flow? and then, how to get the products of shopping cart?

Comment: Could you elaborate? Are you asking of js adding to cart or do you want programatically add item to the quote? What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I use these code to get cart collection:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$minicartModel= $objectManager->create('Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');
$minicartModel->getItems();
```